# Rename titles of sheets for xlswrite

Tags: matlab

I need a bit of help to rename my tabels for xlswrite. I try to use the below code which work as long as the title names are different. However, when I have to identical titels like 'table1' in the example it won't work. How can I search the title strings and if two are identical give them an additional number so my Title array becomes Title={'table1 (1)'; 'table2'; 'table3'; 'table4'; 'table1 (2)';}.

Here is my code

```
Title={'table1'; 'table2'; 'table3'; 'table4'; 'table1';}
[FileNameBodeWrite,PathNameBodeWrite] = uiputfile({'*.xls'},'Save As', [ '.xls']);
filename=[PathNameBodeWrite FileNameBodeWrite];
t=1/numel(Table);
for ii = 1:numel(Table)
    sheet=ii;
    xlswrite(filename,Table{ii},sheet,'A1');
    e = actxserver('Excel.Application'); % # open Activex server
    ewb = e.Workbooks.Open(filename); % # open file (enter full path!)
    ewb.Worksheets.Item(ii).Name = Title{ii,1} % # rename sheets
    ewb.Save % # save to the same file
    ewb.Close(false)
    e.Quit 
end
```

Comment: For future reference, `matlab-guide` is for questions specific to MATLAB's GUIDE GUI development framework. `matlab` is the more generic tag, and is one more people monitor for questions. It's generally helpful to pay attention to the tag descriptions when adding them to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use [`matlab.lang.makeUniqueStrings`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.lang.makeuniquestrings.html) (or [`genvarname`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/genvarname.html) prior to R2014a):

```
Title = {'table1'; 'table2'; 'table3'; 'table4'; 'table1'};
Title = matlab.lang.makeUniqueStrings(Title)

Title =

  5×1 cell array

    'table1'
    'table2'
    'table3'
    'table4'
    'table1_1'
```

Comment: Brilliant gnovice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach looks at the array of title strings and renames those that are repeated.

For example:

```
Title = {'table1'; 'table2'; 'table3'; 'table4'; 'table1'};

[unique_titles, ia, ic] = unique(Title, 'stable');  % Stable to retain order
counts = accumarray(ic, 1);  % Count occurrence of each title

% Iterate only over titles that occur more than once
for ii = ia(counts > 1)
    titleidx = find(ic == ii);  % Find where titles occur
    for jj = 1:counts(ii)
        Title{titleidx(jj)} = sprintf('%s (%u)', unique_titles{ii}, jj);
    end
end
```

Which returns:

```
Title =

  5×1 cell array

    'table1 (1)'
    'table2'
    'table3'
    'table4'
    'table1 (2)'
```